# What are the advantages of a map of maps vs a std::pair as a key

Tags: c++, data-structures, dictionary

What are the advantages and disadvantages of the following ways of making a map that is intended to represent a two dimensional grid. The grid should be able to be filled in at any point, without allocating memory for the whole thing, which is why I didn't just use a 2d array.

```
std::map<int, std::map<int, Tile*>* >* tiles;

std::map<std::pair<int, int>, Tile*>* tiles;
```

Or if you have another better idea let me know. I'm sorry if this is a question that gets asked alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's (obviously) a different data structure and depends on how you access it.

The first one is more like a 2-level tree structure. Map x-coordinates to several y-coordinates to several tiles again. This may sound a little inappropriate to your problem.

The second one does not allow you to get all elements for a specific x-coordinate (or however you may call it). You may not need that anyway?

If you need to map (x,y) coordinates to tile, the 2nd approach might be ok.

Comment: since the keys in a `std::map` are ordered, you can certainly iterate through all elements with a specific x-coordinate. Start with the first key at least as big as make_pair(x, INT_MIN) and continue with subsequent keys until you either reach the end or find one whose x-coordinate is different. What you can't do with either data-structure is easily iterate through elements with a specific y-coordinate.

Comment: So there is not a significant memory or speed problem either way?  Currently I access it as I get the map the x coordinate directs me to and then get the tile the y coordinate directs me to from that map. I've been thinking of it as the main map is a map of columns, and columns and maps of tiles.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a vector of a vector , std::vector< std::vector > ?

It would be better unless your grid is sparse (not every element in the grid has a Tile), and you want to conserve memory. Access time using a vector would be much better if speed is the issue since std::map uses tress as the underlying structure.

Comment: *"Access time using a vector would be much better"* - Unless there are a lot of elements that you have to traverse regularly and you are using a vector of vectors, which kills your data locality.

Comment: You are right, it depends on the access pattern and size of the data.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know how to describe it well, but my grid is sparse, it's intended so that there can be spots on it that are generated with empty area's in between, and that those empty area's are only filled as necessary. So in grid of thousands of possible Tiles then only a few dozen of those might be present initially, but I need to maintain the x,y for position.